# Как изменять размер изображения в html соответственно к экрану монитора ?

Tags: html, php

У изображение размер 500x500. Нужно чтобы этот размер изменялся в соответствие с размером монитора. Например:

**1280, 500x500**
**768, 300x300** - разрешение планшета 
**479, 150x150** - разрешение смартфона

Необходимо реализовать это без использования JavaScript. Возможно это реализовать тупо в самом html или php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью CSS. А если точнее, то [media-запросов](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).

P.S. Вот вам [простенький пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Q6eAv/). Изменяйте ширину фрейма вывода результата. И кстати, вспомнил, что **частично** вашу задачу можно сделать на PHP - [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/). Но там ориентировать можно только на само устройство, с которого пользователь зашел на сайт, а не размеры видимой области браузера.

Comment: возможно ли как то media-запросы подключить как отдельную таблицу ?

Comment: Если вы говорите о "таблице", как о *Cascading Style Sheets — каскадные таблицы стилей*, то да. Можно даже под каждое устройство подключать свой css-файл, например:

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 980px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 649px)">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:2000px)" href="css/Desktop.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:768px)" href="css/Tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:580px)" href="css/Mabile.css" />

когда удаляю содержание внутри таблицы "Mabile.css" почему то автоматически применяются стили "Tablet.css" возможно ли как то этого избежать ??

Comment: @Titan93, попробуйте добавить условие min-width для Tablet.css. А вообще, каждый из медиа-запросов, будет применять стили,  перекрывающие стили в других медиа-запросах или добавлять новые, если они не были заданы ранее.

Comment: заработало, большое спасибо)

Comment: @Titan93, не за что. А вот нажимать "**наградить**" совсем не обязательно, тем более, что пока вы не разбогатели на баллы репутации.